# How to access to a variable defined outside strict context?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have two javascript files:

1. Master.js: contains variable initialization and load the child.js file
2. Child.js: contains a specific set of function

The content of `Master.js` is this:

```
<script src="child.js"></script>

<script>
    var GlobalVariables = {
        'baseUrl": "localhost"
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Child.initialize(true);
    });
</script>
```

as you cans see the `Master.js` file load the `Child.js` file and also create a `GlobalVariables` which I need to use in `Child`.

This is what I done so far in `Child.js`:

```
window.Child = window.Child || {};

(function (exports){
   "use strict";

   exports.GlobalVariables= {};

   exports.initialize = function (bindEventHandlers) {
       bindEventHandlers = bindEventHandlers || true;

       exports.GlobalVariables= GlobalVariables;
   }

   var label = $('#someLabel').html(GlobalVariables.baseUrl);
```

I defined the variable `GlobalVariables` also using `exports.`, but I can access to it using `GlobalVariables.baseUrl` only in the `initialize` function, in the `label` I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GlobalVariables is not defined

What I did wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok, thanks to @Quentin answer I was able to apply the following edit to my code:

```
exports.initialize = function (bindEventHandlers) {
   bindEventHandlers = bindEventHandlers || true;

   if (bindEventHandlers) {
        _bindEventHandlers();
   }
}

function _bindEventHandlers() {
  var label = $('#someLabel').html(GlobalVariables.baseUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *child.js* you attempt to read the value of `GlobalVariables` **then** in your inline script, you declare `GlobalVariables` and give it a value.

You have to declare the variable **before** you can read from it.

Comment: for "before" you mean outside the `function (exports)`?

Comment: @Rockj — I mean the literal order of the scripts. You have two scripts. 1 and 2. You do stuff in 1 which cannot be done until 2 is done.